# How to Create Custom Routing controller in .net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I have a problem, I want to create a specific routing for the controller, as in the example below :
My Controller name= Company
My Action=index

www.mysite.com/CompanyName

Comment: [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is first search result of all search engines if you search for *asp.net core routing*. If for any reason the link is not helpful, please consider adding more details and description to the question, sharing what you have tried so far and ask a specific question after taking a look at [ASK].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [Route()] Annotation top of your controller to set routing for controller. for example if place [Route("api/{controller}")] means that route is controllerName otherwise you can place [Route("api/yourroute")] top of controller for custom routing.

each action has its name for routing. for example for get action method that return list you can place [HttpGet("list")] top of action.